# How to write array request body in rest assured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have used rest assured framework, This is the request body for post method

```
{
  "requestNumber":749 ,
  "referenceNumber": "tyryrty",
  "cardType": "aliqua pariatur enim cupidatat",
  "companyName": "amet Lorem",
  "rejectMessage": "tempor dolor officia",
  "contactEmail": "mollit pariatur veniam sed",
  "serviceProviderEmailList": [
    "ipsum nis",
    "Ut dolore aliqua exercitation irure"
  ],
  "approvedBy": "sup",
  "approvedDate": "1962-07-15T01:00:55.437Z"
}
```

I have tried in this way but i'm not getting result

```
 
JSONObject jsonobj1 = new JSONObject();
            jsonobj1.put("requestNumber", 749 );
            jsonobj1.put("referenceNumber", "tyryrty");
            jsonobj1.put("cardType", "aliqua pariatur enim cupidatat");
            jsonobj1.put("companyName", "amet Lorem");
            jsonobj1.put("contactEmail", "tempor dolor officia");
            Map<String, Object> map= new HashMap<String,Object>();
            map.put("serviceProviderEmailList", "ipsum nis");
            List<Map<String, Object>> test=Arrays.asList(map);
            jsonobj1.put("serviceProviderEmailList", test);
            
            jsonobj1.put("approvedBy", "sup");
            jsonobj1.put("approvedDate", "1962-07-15T01:00:55.437Z");
```

Comment: Create List<serviceProviderEmailList> emaiList , and then add this to the map
eg : map.put("serviceProviderEmailList", emaiList")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For better readability, You can convert the JSON to a Java object and then pass it to Rest Assured. For e.g. you can convert it to a Java collection as shown below. This process is called as Serialisation.

Under the hood, Rest Assured will use libraries like Jackson Data Bind to de-serialize it and send along with the request.

Here's the sample code you can use:

```
    List<String> serviceProviderEmailList = new ArrayList<>();
    serviceProviderEmailList.add("element1");
    serviceProviderEmailList.add("element2");

    HashMap<String, Object> rootJsonObject = new HashMap<>();
    rootJsonObject.put("requestNumber", 749);
    rootJsonObject.put("cardType", "value");
    rootJsonObject.put("companyName", "value");
    rootJsonObject.put("rejectMessage", "value");
    rootJsonObject.put("contactEmail", "value");
    rootJsonObject.put("serviceProviderEmailList", serviceProviderEmailList);
    rootJsonObject.put("approvedBy", "value");
    rootJsonObject.put("approvedDate", "value");

    given().
            body(rootJsonObject).
    when().
            post("endpoint");
```

Please don't forget to add Jackson Data bind as a dependency in your project. For e.g. if you are using Maven, you can add it as below in your pom.xml.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```